# php - Storing posted JSON object in database

Tags: java, php, mysql, json

I'm reading a large json file with Java and post each line of my localhost, which then takes the JSON and reads it as an object, then stores parts of the object in that database using MySQL.

This is a really slow process.

How can I optimize it?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$json = $_POST['data'];

if(!empty($json)){

    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $user_id =  $obj->interaction->author->id;
    $user_link =  $obj->interaction->author->link;
    $name =  $obj->interaction->author->name;
    $user_name =  $obj->interaction->author->username;
    $user_gender =  $obj->demographic->gender;
    $user_language =  $obj->twitter->lang;
    $user_image =  $obj->interaction->author->avatar;
    $user_klout =  $obj->klout->score;
    $user_confidence =  $obj->language->confidence;
    $user_desc =  $obj->twitter->user->description;
    $user_timezone =  $obj->twitter->user->time_zone;
    $user_tweet_count = $obj->twitter->user->statuses_count;
    $user_followers_count = $obj->twitter->user->followers_count;
    $user_friends_count = $obj->twitter->user->friends_count;
    $user_location = $obj->twitter->user->location;
    $user_created_at = $obj->twitter->user->created_at;

    $tweet_id =  $obj->twitter->id;
    $tweet_text =  $obj->interaction->content;
    $tweet_link =  $obj->interaction->link;

    $tweet_created_at =  $obj->interaction->created_at;

    $tweet_location =  $obj->twitter->user->location;

    //$tweet_geo_lat =  $obj->interaction->geo->latitude;
    //$tweet_geo_long =  $obj->interaction->geo->longitude;

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "cohort");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tweeters (user_id, screen_name, name, profile_image_url, location, url,
            description, created_at, followers_count,
            friends_count, statuses_count, time_zone,
            last_update, klout, confidence, gender
    )
    VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_name','$name',
    '$user_image', '$user_location', '$user_link',
    '$user_desc', '$user_created_at', '$user_followers_count',
    '$user_friends_count', '$user_tweet_count', '$user_timezone',
    '', '$user_klout', '$user_confidence', '$user_gender' )";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO search_tweets (tweet_id, tweet_text, created_at_date,
        created_at_time, location, geo_lat,
        geo_long, user_id, is_rt)
        VALUES ('$tweet_id', '$tweet_text','',
                '$tweet_created_at', '$tweet_location', '',
                '', '$user_id', '')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode(array("id" => $user_id ));
}

?>
```

Java:

```
    String inputfile = "D:\\Datasift\\Tweets.json"; //  Source File Name.  
        double nol = 200000; //  No. of lines to be split and saved in each output file.  
        File file = new File(inputfile);  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);  
        int count = 0;  
        System.out.println("Storing file in stack"); 
        int may = 0, june = 0, just_june=0, july = 0;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        BufferedReader  in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (new ReverseLineInputStream(file)));


        while(true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            //System.out.println("X:" + line);
            // Send POST output.
            URL url1;
        URLConnection   urlConn;
        DataOutputStream    printout;
        DataInputStream     input;
                // URL of CGI-Bin script.
        url1 = new URL ("http://localhost/json/");
                // URL connection channel.
        urlConn = url1.openConnection();
                // Let the run-time system (RTS) know that we want input.
        urlConn.setDoInput (true);
                // Let the RTS know that we want to do output.
        urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
                // No caching, we want the real thing.
        urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
                // Specify the content type.
        urlConn.setRequestProperty
        ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream ());
            String content =
                "data=" + URLEncoder.encode (line);
            printout.writeBytes (content);
            printout.flush ();
            printout.close ();
            // Get response data.
            input = new DataInputStream (urlConn.getInputStream ());
            String str;
            while (null != ((str = input.readLine()))){
                //System.out.println (str);                   
            }

            input.close ();
        }
        System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to troll in any way, but why don't you just read the file with PHP ?

Comment: lol, I thought of that, but that would mean that the page will be loading for as long as the storage takes, right?

Comment: Ah, I understand now, you are trying to detach back-end jobs from public requests. There is no need to use  two technologies (java and php), just use one. I'm guessing there is a signal that starts the storage process. You can start it the same way from php as you do with java 'C:\php file.php' (if(windows)). You can also start it in the background with exec() from you php script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are repeating this process multiple times one way of doing it is using multiple data sets.

So rather than doing INSERT INTO table (field,field) VALUES (value,value) and looping it many times you would do $ins = "INSERT INTO table (field, field) VALUES"; then within your foreach loop (or each time you call the code) build up an array $ins_values[] = "(escaped_value,escaped_value)"; and then run the query $ins.implode(',',$ins_values).

Mysql will run much faster in this context although beware that Mysql sets data limits on max_allowed_packet which might need adjusting depending.

Hope that helps and I've understood your question correctly.